# Write Eigen VectorXd in CSV format

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I'm trying to write an `Eigen::VectorXd` to a CSV file. The vector is from a row of an `Eigen::MatrixXd`. My function is defined as follows:

```
void writeMatrixToCSVwithID(fs::path path, VectorXd row, unsigned long int row_id){
    const static IOFormat CSVFormat(StreamPrecision, DontAlignCols, ", ", "\n");
    ofstream file(path.c_str(), std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
    row.resize(1, row.size());
    file << row_id << ", " << row.format(CSVFormat) << std::endl;
    file.close();
}
```

The problem is this generates a file as:

```
11, 0.247795
0.327012
0.502336
0.569316
0.705254
12, 0.247795
0.327012
0.502336
0.569316
0.705254
```

The expected output is:

```
11, 0.247795, 0.327012, 0.502336, 0.569316, 0.705254
12, 0.247795, 0.327012, 0.502336, 0.569316, 0.705254
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the error is that Eigen outputs VectorXd as a column. `MatrixXd::row(id)` returns `Block` which seems to output either a row or column extract as a column!

Thus, rather than passing the `VectorXd` row, I now pass the row as a `MatrixXd`. The `IOFormat` object is initialised with the row separator as ','.

```
void writeMatrixToCSVwithID(fs::path path, MatrixXd row, unsigned long int row_id){
    const static IOFormat CSVFormat(StreamPrecision, DontAlignCols, ", ", ", ");
    ofstream file(path.c_str(), std::ofstream::app);
    row.resize(1, row.size()); // Making sure that we are dealing with a row.
    file << row_id << ", " << row.format(CSVFormat) << std::endl;
    file.close();
}
```

This produces the desired row wise output.